# Call a function that has parameter type inside another function c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

i got this function on my form:

```
private void UpdateQuantityDataGridView(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   (...codes)
}
```

and i want to call that function inside another function, let's say when i click a "OK" button, this below function will run and execute above function that has parameter type.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // This is the "OK" button click handler.
{
  SubmitButton(sender, e);
}

private void SubmitButton(object sender, EventArgs e) // This is function of "OK" button
{
  (...codes)
  UpdateQuantityDataGridView("What should i put in here? I tried (sender, e), but it is useless")
}
```

I know that this function run when we put something like this:
`dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewSystemEventHandler(...);`

But, i don't want that because that function will only run if the cell value in DataGridView has been changed, i want to access that function when i click "OK" button. But, what should i put inside a parameters value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the logic currently in the `UpdateQuantityDataGridView()` method and put it into a new `public` method named whatever you want, then you can call this logic from anywhere in your class or any other code that references your class, like this:

```
public void DoUpdateQuantityLogic()
{
    // Put logic here
}
```

Note: If you do not actually use `sender` or `e`, then you can leave the method above without parameters, but if you do use `e`, for example, then you need to have a parameter for the `DoUpdateQuantityLogic()` method to account for what the property of the `e` object you are using is.

Now you can call `DoUpdateQuantityLogic()` from you other methods, like this:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // This is the "OK" button click handler.
{
    DoUpdateQuantityLogic();
}

private void SubmitButton(object sender, EventArgs e) // This is function of "OK" button
{
    DoUpdateQuantityLogic();
}
```

This allows you to re-use your logic and also isolates the functionality into a method that makes unit testing easier, if you choose to unit test this logic.

If you are determined to use your existing event-based method infrastructure, then you can pass `null` for both the `sender` and the `e` arguments of the event handler, like this:

```
UpdateQuantityDataGridView(null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks sir @Karl Anderson, i got it now :)

Answer (score 2):

If your method `UpdateQuantityDataGridView()` actually using the parameters `sender` and `e`? If not just pass null for both.

```
UpdateQuantityDataGridView(null, null);
```

If you are using them:

```
var e = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs();
// assign any properties
UpdateQuantityDataGridView(dataGridView1, e);
```

Comment: Thanks sir @luisperezphd, i got it now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sender**, but you can't use **e** because **UpdateQuantityDataGridView** needs **e** to be of type **DataGridViewCellEventArgs**.

Depending on what your **UpdateQuantityDataGridView** handler wants to do with the **e** parameter, you could just pass **null** when you call it from your **SubmitButton**. 
Otherwise, you'll have to **new** a **DataGridViewCellEventArgs** and populate it with the appropriate values your own handler requires/expects.